# Error ngRoute only on smartphones browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

my website is working well on computer browsers but when I'm trying to execute it on a smartphone browser I've an error telling me that I have an "Error: [$injector:modulerr]".

I have included the angular.min.js (1.4.7) and the angular-route.min.js (1.4.7)

**index.html**

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
    'use strict';

/* App Module */

var arevia = angular.module('arevia', ['ngRoute','areviaControllers','areviaServices','ngToast']);

arevia.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/home.min.html',
        url: '/protected'
    }).
    when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/profile.min.html'
    }).
    when('/inspirations', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/inspirations.min.html'
    }).
    when('/interventions', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/interventions.min.html'
    }).
    when('/whyArevia', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/whyArevia.min.html'
    }).
    when('/shop', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/shop.min.html'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/contact.min.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl'
    }).
    when('/noNewsletter/:email/:token', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/noNewsletter.min.html',
        controller: 'NewsletterCtrl'
    }).
    when('/theWorldOfArevia', {
        templateUrl: '/Arevia/appEN/partials/theWorldOfArevia.min.html',
        controller: 'BlogCtrl',
        resolve: {
            session: ['SessionResolver', function resolveSession(SessionResolver) {
                return SessionResolver.resolve();
            }]
        },
        redirection: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) {
            if(AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
                return '/theWorldOfArevia';
            }
        }]
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

By the way all my scripts and Html documents are minified (idk if it's usefull...).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have gotten this error before and clearing my cache worked. no idea why

Comment: Ok I did too, but still blocked ...